# How to transfrom existing JSON output so it matches desired format

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a `json` output from a `mysql` stored procedure. Everything works fine, but I need to transform the `json` output to another desired format.

My `json` looks as follow (which is the result of a simple `json_encode` on the `mysql`query):

```
[
    {
        "stack": monday,
        "name": "banana",
        "i_value_p": "1.1",
        "i_value_n": "2.9",
        "i_value_u": "0.0"
    },
    {
        "stack": monday,
        "name": "apple",
        "i_value_p": "1.5",
        "i_value_n": "3.9",
        "i_value_u": "0.0"
    },
    {
        "stack": monday,
        "name": "grape",
        "i_value_p": "1.1",
        "i_value_n": "3.1",
        "i_value_u": "0.0"
    },
    {
        "stack": wednesday,
        "name": "banana",
        "i_value_p": "2.4",
        "i_value_n": "6.0",
        "i_value_u": "0.0"
    },
    {
        "stack": wednesday,
        "name": "apple",
        "i_value_p": "3.0",
        "i_value_n": "7.6",
        "i_value_u": "0.0"
    },
    {
        "stack": wednesday,
        "name": grape",
        "i_value_p": "2.3",
        "i_value_n": "6.0",
        "i_value_u": "0.0",
        "fill_color": "#0B62A4"
    },
    {
        "stack": friday,
        "name": "banana",
        "i_value_p": "2.2",
        "i_value_n": "6.5",
        "i_value_u": "0.0"
    },
    {
        "stack": friday,
        "name": "apple",
        "i_value_p": "3.0",
        "i_value_n": "7.9",
        "i_value_u": "0.0"
    },
    {
        "stack": friday,
        "name": "grape",
        "i_value_p": "2.0",
        "i_value_n": "5.4",
        "i_value_u": "0.0"
    }
]
```

What I would like to have is the following `json` output:

```
[
    {
        name: "i_value_p",
        data: [1.1, 1.5, 1.1,], //banana, apple, grape
        stack: "monday"
    }, 
    {
        name: "i_value_n",
        data: [2.9, 3.9, 2.1], //banana, apple, grape
        stack: "monday"
    }, 
    {
        name: 'i_value_u',
        data: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], //banana, apple, grape
        stack: "monday"
    }

// and the same goes for the wednesday and friday

]
```

In my query, `i_value_p`, `i_value_n`, `i_value_u` are always fixed columns and will not vary. The amount of fruits and days can vary.

My question now is: in `php`, how can I transform my `mysql` output to an `array` which (after I do a `json_encode`) gives me the desired `json` output.

My `php` code for the `mysql` query:

```
$stmt = $dbdto->prepare("CALL testSO(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('iiiiissi', $val1, $val2, $val3, $val4, $val5, $val6, $vl7, $val8);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

$data = array();
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
  $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

I already started something, but I could'nt figure it out:

```
$stmt = $dbdto->prepare("CALL testSO(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('iiiiissi', $val1, $val2, $val3, $val4, $val5, $val6, $vl7, $val8);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

$data = array();
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

$newdata = array();
$arr = ["i_value_p", "i_value_n", "i_value_u"];

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $row_array = array();
    $row_array["name"] = $item;
    $row_array["data"] = array();
    //loop fruits
    foreach ($data as $d) {

    }
    array_push($newdata, $row_array);
}
```

This doesn't (obviously) gives me any results yet.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are much easier ways to solve your problem. This might help you, not sure if the desired output may be the one you are looking for. If not, you might design a similar one.

#### Original Input

```
$data = '[
    {
        "stack": "monday",
        "name": "banana",
        "i_value_p": "1.1",
        "i_value_n": "2.9",
        "i_value_u": "0.0"
    },
    {
        "stack": "monday",
        "name": "apple",
        "i_value_p": "1.5",
        "i_value_n": "3.9",
        "i_value_u": "0.0"
    },
    {
        "stack": "monday",
        "name": "grape",
        "i_value_p": "1.1",
        "i_value_n": "3.1",
        "i_value_u": "0.0"
    },
    {
        "stack": "wednesday",
        "name": "banana",
        "i_value_p": "2.4",
        "i_value_n": "6.0",
        "i_value_u": "0.0"
    },
    {
        "stack": "wednesday",
        "name": "apple",
        "i_value_p": "3.0",
        "i_value_n": "7.6",
        "i_value_u": "0.0"
    },
    {
        "stack": "wednesday",
        "name": "grape",
        "i_value_p": "2.3",
        "i_value_n": "6.0",
        "i_value_u": "0.0",
        "fill_color": "#0B62A4"
    },
    {
        "stack": "friday",
        "name": "banana",
        "i_value_p": "2.2",
        "i_value_n": "6.5",
        "i_value_u": "0.0"
    },
    {
        "stack": "friday",
        "name": "apple",
        "i_value_p": "3.0",
        "i_value_n": "7.9",
        "i_value_u": "0.0"
    },
    {
        "stack": "friday",
        "name": "grape",
        "i_value_p": "2.0",
        "i_value_n": "5.4",
        "i_value_u": "0.0"
    }
]'; //original JSON
```

#### Script

```
newData(json_decode($data, true)); // call newData function

function newData($data)
{

    $newData = array(); // new array
    $helper_array = array('p', 'n', 'u'); // different chars
    $c = 0; // counter to 3
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data); $i++) {
        array_push($newData, array(
            'data' => array(
                (float) $data[$i * $c]["i_value_" . $helper_array[$c]],
                (float) $data[$i * $c + 1]["i_value_" . $helper_array[$c]],
                (float) $data[$i * $c + 2]["i_value_" . $helper_array[$c]],
            ),
            'stack' => $data[$i]["stack"],
            'name' => array_search($data[$i]["i_value_" . $helper_array[$c++]], $data[$i]),
        ));
        if ($c === 3) {$c = 0;} // once $c reaches to 3, it would set it back to zero
    }

    //var_dump(json_encode($newData)); //view desired output

    return json_encode($newData);
}
```

#### Desired Output

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      1.1,
      1.5,
      1.1
    ],
    "stack": "monday",
    "name": "i_value_p"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      3.9,
      3.1,
      6
    ],
    "stack": "monday",
    "name": "i_value_n"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "stack": "monday",
    "name": "i_value_u"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      1.1,
      1.5,
      1.1
    ],
    "stack": "wednesday",
    "name": "i_value_p"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      7.6,
      6,
      6.5
    ],
    "stack": "wednesday",
    "name": "i_value_n"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "stack": "wednesday",
    "name": "i_value_u"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      1.1,
      1.5,
      1.1
    ],
    "stack": "friday",
    "name": "i_value_p"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      7.9,
      5.4,
      0
    ],
    "stack": "friday",
    "name": "i_value_n"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "stack": "friday",
    "name": "i_value_u"
  }
]
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed. Your help is much appreciated! I will mark your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    $json = '[
                {
                    "stack": "monday",
                    "name": "banana",
                    "i_value_p": "1.1",
                    "i_value_n": "2.9",
                    "i_value_u": "0.0"
                },
                {
                    "stack": "monday",
                    "name": "apple",
                    "i_value_p": "1.5",
                    "i_value_n": "3.9",
                    "i_value_u": "0.0"
                },
                {
                    "stack": "monday",
                    "name": "grape",
                    "i_value_p": "1.1",
                    "i_value_n": "3.1",
                    "i_value_u": "0.0"
                },
                {
                    "stack": "wednesday",
                    "name": "banana",
                    "i_value_p": "2.4",
                    "i_value_n": "6.0",
                    "i_value_u": "0.0"
                }
            ]';

    $data = json_decode($json);
    $arr = ["i_value_p", "i_value_n", "i_value_u"];

    $row_array = array();
    foreach ($data as $item => $obj) {
        $row_array[$obj->stack]['i_value_p'][] = $obj->i_value_p;
        $row_array[$obj->stack]['i_value_n'][] = $obj->i_value_n;
        $row_array[$obj->stack]['i_value_u'][] = $obj->i_value_u;
    }

    $newdata = array();
    foreach ($row_array as $stack => $values) {
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            $newdata[] = array(
                'stack' => $stack,
                'data' => $value,
                'name' => $key,
            );
        }
    }

    print(json_encode($newdata));
```